# Divi + Woocommerce Child Theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have experience with Wordpress & Woocommerce but this is the first time I have used Divi + Woocommerce and it's been a while since I worked with WP so I may be a little rusty. I am a full stack developer so any technical answers are fine.

I have created a child theme without any issues but when I try to copy the Woocommerce folder into the child theme to make changes to the .php file (e.g. /child-theme/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php) as I have done before (non-divi) it doesn't override.

I have added the child theme comment to the child theme styles.css as follows

```
/*
Theme Name: Theme Child
Version: 1.0
Description: Child theme for Main theme.
Author: Me
Template: theme 
*/
```

Comment: Is the new .php file in your Appearance > Editor (right sidebar). I'm also using Divi + WC (lovin' Divi).

Comment: No it's not there. It's not a custom template file BTW. It's a copy of the woocommerce file /woocommerce/templates/content-product.php

Answer (score 2):

I needed to remove the subdirectory "templates" from the child theme woocommerce folder.

Answer (score 0):

From here you can download the free Divi Child Theme: https://divireadythemes.com/download-a-free-blank-divi-child-theme/

```
/*
Theme Name: Divi Child Theme
Theme URI: https://YourURL.com/
Description: Divi Child Theme
Author: Areeb Saeed Raja
Author URI: https://YourURL.com/
Template: Divi
Version: Updated for Divi 3+
*/
```